# Whether to indicate "job sharing" option in application

Tags: job-search, faculty-application, application-cover-letter, two-body-problem

I am applying for a job that in the call mentions that the university supports "job sharing and advancement of dual-career couples".  My partner and I are applying both to that position (we have similar qualifications).  Should we indicate in our respective application letters that we are interested in the job sharing option in any way?  Or is that something that will come up later in the process?

What if one of us gets invited for a job interview but not the other?  If one of us is a stronger candidate, might it hurt the other if we indicate the job sharing option?  (We also have coauthored papers together, so reviewers should find out pretty quickly that we're related in some way.)

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this, but it seems like an unnecessary complication to raise it early. Would you be happy enough if one of you got the job?

Comment: @Buffy Yes, we'd be more than happy if either of us gets it.

Comment: Maybe best to just let it go for now. See what develops. But, again, outside my "lane".

Answer (score 7):

Difficult question. Here are my thoughts, too long for a comment.

The fact that the university explicitly supports job sharing suggests that asking about it in your particular case would make sense.

It is possible that the explicit support is just pro forma. Can you find out whether there are any couples presently sharing a job? Do you have any contacts at the school to ask informally?

In your response to  @Buffy 's comment, you say you'd be OK if just one of you gets the job. Then I'd concur in waiting.

Speaking personally from my experience on hiring committees, I would appreciate knowing this information early, particularly the fact that one job would be acceptable even if two were preferable. For me it would strengthen the application(s).

Comment: I might jump the other way on the last sentence, but it is hard to say.

Comment: I'd also note that if one of the OPs gets the job then the other has some freedom to explore options. Job sharing might be more advantageous for the institution than for the individuals. Worth thinking about, anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely tricky.  The "job sharing" sentence in the call also appears on calls for other jobs at the university, so it does look like a pro forma clause.  And what @Buffy mentions, that we'd have some more freedom if one of us gets the job, is also worth considering. Like what if they really want one of us? Then we might even have room to negotiate a partner hire, instead of a job share.  It's just so hard to know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anyone at the university and information about 50% positions isn't listed on any of the departmental websites, so I don't know how I'd find out about other job sharing couples.  — I'm going to leave this open for a little longer to see if others chime in ...

Comment: An hiring the other one in a future cycle is also possible.

Comment: @jan If you're willing, come back here and tell us what happened when the dust has settled ...

Comment: @EthanBolker Will do :)  but it will be a while, the post doesn't start until early 2022 so I don't expect any results before mid-2021 ...

Answer (score 1):

Negotiating a job for your spouse, or a job sharing arrangement, is very difficult in normal times.  Currently, there is a pandemic and layoffs are more common than hiring.  As a result, I suggest that you don't try to negotiate or even hint that you will negotiate until you have a binding job offer in hand.  And don't expect to succeed.

Be prepared to answer questions about what you want at any stage of the interview process.  Have answers ready that will lead the hiring committee to believe that hiring you will be easy.